# How to compare only the date part in ServiceStack OrmLite query

Tags: c#, datetime, compare, ormlite-servicestack

I need to compare `DateTime` value with the datetime field using OrmLite in ServiceStack.

I have visited several threads, but nothing specified on this topic earlier. The OrmLitte SQL I have is something like:

```
Db.Select<Table1>(q => q.Where(x => x.creationDate >= creationDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try creating a poco like:

`public class Table1 // or Person for example
    {
        public string Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public DateTime Dob {get; set;}
    }`

Then you can do:

```
var creationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
Db.Select<Table1>(q => q.Where(p => p.Dob.Date >= creationDate.Date));
```

Comment: p.Dob is null exception will throw

Answer (score 1):

You should use **raw sql** for this

Something like this:

```
var query = db.From<Table1>();
var date = query.CreateParam("date", creationDate, dbType: DbType.Date);
query.Params.Add(date);
query.UnsafeWhere("CAST(creationDate AS DATE) =  CAST(@date AS DATE)");
return db.Select(query)
```

Or this:

```
var date = db.CreateParam("date", creationDate, dbType: DbType.Date);
return db.Select<Table1>("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CAST(creationDate AS DATE) =  CAST(@date AS DATE)", new[] { date });
```